# How do I to implement MATLAB's edge() function in Python OpenCV or skimage

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

I want to replicate MATLAB's `edge()` detection function in Python.

There are two Python functions I know of that implement the Canny filter:

```py
import cv2
edges = cv2.Canny(image)
```

and

```py
from skimage import feature
edges = feature.canny(image)
```

However, neither of these Python functions is capable of computing the filter's high and low threshold in the same manner MATLAB does. According  to [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811908001171).

MATLAB Code

```matlab
farm = imread('small_farms.JPG');%change this to the 
file path of image
imshow(farm);%this shows the original image
gfarm = rgb2gray(farm);
figure,
imshow(gfarm);%show grayscaled image
A = medfilt2(gfarm,[4 4]);
figure,
imshow(A);
B = edge(A,'log');
figure,
imshow(B,[]);
```

Comment: "Neither of these Python functions", which Python functions? You haven't mentioned any.

Comment: @Adriaan I just edited the code for more clarity

Comment: Different implementations work differently and need different threshold values to achieve similar results. Don't try to force one tool to work the same as another. Your link does not seem to go to any Matlab information.

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/06/zero-parameter-automatic-canny-edge-detection-with-python-and-opencv/